# Dynamics CRM 2011: How can I activate an update trigger on 580 records without changing them?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

During an update of an internal CRM installation, I forgot to include the SDK processing steps for create, update and delete of a new entity I added. Afterwards, I ran a tool to import about 580 records of this type. Unfortunately, this means that these 580 records didn't trigger The create step. However, if I can trigger the Update step for all these records without changing them, it should be fine.

I now added the relevant steps to the Dynamics CRM installation, but I'm still trying to figure out how to best trigger an Update on all 580 records. does reassigning the record also trigger an Update? if not, is there a better way to trigger these updates without actually changing any of the data that was imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some things on the development server, and it looks like reassigning these records does trigger an update. This seems like the easiest way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a very simple workflow that only has a single step - Update entity. By default it will not change any fields but it will raise the trigger event. Then select the entities you want to trigger (250 max at a time, so you'll have to do it 3 times, but probably not a big deal) and run the workflow.